# video mp4 and flv on server does not play. Only buffers

Tags: php, video, video-streaming, swfobject

I'm having a problem with ...I'm having a problem with the video taking forever to load, then when it loads and buffer, plays for a little bit then begins pause and buffer then play, and so on..

Below code in a test file I am running.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="swfobject.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var so = new SWFObject('mediaplayer.swf','mpl','470','320','9');
so.addParam('allowscriptaccess','always');
so.addParam('allowfullscreen','true');
so.addParam('flashvars','&file=video_1506099373.mp4&autostart=false&repeat=true&preload=1');
so.write('player');
</script>
```

I am running videos on CENTOS 6.8. Videos are buffering a lot. Even one second buffer and other one second it run. A lot of time is going to load video first and then play.

I would like to mention here that a minimum size of my video is 200MB and largest size is 2GB.

I am not having this as Streaming server. I wanna try something which works at my end.

Can I get it done at server side? Any configuration in server side or code level?
Any help??